# Is it good practice to assign ranges to userid?

Tags: database, foreign-keys, schema, primary-key, userid

I'm building a database schema for users of my app, and I am thinking of setting the userid value according to user type. So, 
buyers: 10001 to 19999 
sellers: 20001 to 29999
shippers: 30001 to 39999

Next, I assign unique email addresses to the userid:
Login_table

Email.......password.......userid

aaaaa@yy.com....... password.......10005  ---> this email belong to user 10005 (a buyer)

bbbbb@yy.com.......password.......20008  ---> this email belongs to user 20008 (a seller)

ccccc@yy.com.......password.......30187  ---> this email belongs to user 30187 (a shipper)

I then have 3 tables for buyers, sellers, and shippers because each may have different attributes:

buyer_table

buyerid.......name.......   mother

10005.......     John.......   Mary

10006 .......    Chris.......  Nancy

seller_table

sellerid.......   name.......   pet

20008 .......    Adam.......    Dog

20018 .......    Tony  .......  cat

shipper_table

shipperid.......   name.......    car

30187.......       George.......  GMC

30188  .......     Larry .......  Honda

The advantage here is that I have a single login_table for all user types. I do not want to have 3 login tables for each type.  Based on the userid value I know what type of user it is.  Keeping three tables for each user (buyer_table, seller_table, and shipper_table) is good for making the schema more understandable, in addition to being able to assign different attributes to each user type.
Sounds good?  Maybe.

However, I have a problem in that the login_table refers to “userid” while the three user tables each has a different id name for the user, so in the buyer_table I have buyerid as primary key, in the seller_table it is sellerid as primary key, and finally in the shipper_table, the shipperid is the primary key.
How can I link these three primary keys to the login_table?  The login_table has userid as a foreign key to one of those three tables, but it is called “userid”, not buyerid, or sellerid, or shipperid!

1) Is it a good idea to classify the userid value according to ranges?

2) If so, how can I resolve the PK-FK issue as described above?

3) Am I off completely?

Comment: I've seen this many times. My experience suggests you will regret this. Sooner than you imagine.

Answer (score -1):

Having ranges of values for different kinds of similar objects is not bad. If you feel like doing so, you could use sequences wich support value ranges. This way, you could have a buyer sequence wich goes from 0-1000, a seller one from 1001 to 2000 and so on. That would also help you keeping track of the increasing index of the different kinds!